# Add vanilla-tilt.js to Angular 6 component (external JS library in Angular component)

Tags: angular

I would like to use a third party js library called vanilla-tilt.js in one of my Angular components. Here is the link to the library:

https://micku7zu.github.io/vanilla-tilt.js/

What I've done so far is: Installed with npm and linked it into my angular.json file like so:

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/vanilla-tilt/dist/vanilla-tilt.js"
]
```

Then in my component.ts I did the following (I'm only supplying the necessary code and `'.about-pic'` is the `<img>` I am selecting in my HTML file):

```
import { VanillaTilt } from 'vanilla-tilt/dist/vanilla-tilt.js';

export class AboutComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    VanillaTilt.init(document.querySelector('.about-pic'), {
      max: 25,
      speed: 400
    });
  }
}
```

I got the code in `ngAfterViewInit()` from the website I linked above, under "JS Way"

I thought I imported this external library correctly, but I am getting the following error in the console:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined`

I guess am not quite understanding the concept of installing third-party JS libraries in Angular components. What can I try next?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50824362/5695162) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50303509/5695162)

Answer (score 2):

As per https://micku7zu.github.io/vanilla-tilt.js/ JS way, i tried the same in ngOnInit. It worked for me.

1. npm install vanilla-tilt
2. **declare var VanillaTilt** in ts file
3. ngOnInit() {

   VanillaTilt.init(document.querySelector(".tilt-image"), {
     max: 25,
     speed: 400
   });

   VanillaTilt.init(document.querySelectorAll(".tilt-image"));

   }
4. In html 
   div class="tilt tilt-image" data-tilt data-tilt-glare="true" data-tilt-scale="1.1"
   img src="assets/images/sample.png"
   /div

Note : "tilt-image" is your element

Comment: declare and init fixed it.
FYI - In Angular when you move vanilla-tilt html from index/main page to component they don't work. The solution is to initialize the related elements as mentioned above.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to run this in Angular 9+, you need to import vanilla-tilt first
so:

import 'vanilla-tilt';
declare var VanillaTilt;

will work

Answer (score 0):

I've just released https://www.npmjs.com/package/@geometricpanda/angular-tilt

This supports all functionality of the original jQuery package - and i'm going to be updating it with the newer features from vanilla tilt.

The main difference here is that @geometricpanda/angular-tilt doesnt use DOM api's directly, but leverages angular's Renderer2, @HostBindings, and @HostListeners - meaning that it's safe for Angular Universal rendering (or prerendering), and doesnt cause issues in DOM simulated environments such as JSDOM (Jest)

Answer (score 0):

*Worked on Angular 14:*

install package:

```
npm install vanilla-tilt
```

then import ElementRef (to get the DOM element) and VanillaTilt (to add effects) packages in your component:

```
import {Component, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import VanillaTilt from "vanilla-tilt";
```

add ElementRef in the constructor:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
}
```

in the ngOnInit method, tell angular where to put effects (need to precise the css class name:

```
ngOnInit() {
// add vanilla-tilt effect on .<class-name> cards
VanillaTilt.init(
  this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(".class-name"), { max: 20, speed: 300, scale: 1.05 }
);}
```

All elements with the given class name will have the wanted effects ^_^

To modify the effects, you can change parameters in the second argument of .init() method. Available parameters here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vanilla-tilt#options

Have fun with it!